# Issues Creating cookie with evercookie using js api in php

Tags: java, javascript, php, cookies, evercookie

I want to create permanent cookie with ever cookie but when i run ever cookie program on localhost (Php wamp server) it does not create any cookie and following error is displayed

```
Not Found
The requested URL /php/evercookie_etag.php was not found on this server.

Not Found
The requested URL /php/evercookie_cache.php was not found on this server.
```

I have downloaded it from this link http://github.com/samyk/evercookie

I want to create a permanent cookie so that i can recognize the system on which i run my web page below is my code, Please help to sort out my issue, thanks in advance....

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/swfobject-2.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/evercookie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
//var ec = new evercookie();  
var ec = new evercookie({
        baseurl: '/test', http://localhost/test
        asseturi: '/assets', http://localhost/test/assets
        phpuri: '/php' http://localhost/test/php
    });


ec.set("id", "12345");


ec.get("id", function(value) { alert("Cookie value is " + value) });


function getCookie(best_candidate, all_candidates)
{
    alert("The retrieved cookie is: " + best_candidate + "\n" +
        "You can see what each storage mechanism returned " +
        "by looping through the all_candidates object.");

    for (var item in all_candidates)
        document.write("Storage mechanism " + item +
            " returned " + all_candidates[item] + " votes<br>");
}
ec.get("id", getCookie);
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that your baseurl var is '/test' ? For example with the github source, it will be :

```
var ec = new evercookie({
    baseurl: '/evercookie-master',
    asseturi: '/assets',
    phpuri: '/php'
});
```